# How to structure E2E tests with Appium/Cucumber for Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, cucumber, cross-platform, appium, e2e-testing

We are starting to structure our UI e2e tests using Appium / Cucumber / Ruby stack.
Since we are using Xamarin Forms we obviously want to test for iOS and Android.
In the end we want to upload the tests to App Center to run in several devices, get the reports and etc.

Cucumber normally uses this directory structure:

E2E

----FEATURES

--------SUPPORT

------------env.rb

------------hooks.rb

--------STEP_DEFINITIONS

------------home_steps.rb

--------Home.feature

The problem starts with the env.rb file, that contains all the Appium desired capabilities and they are completely different or iOS and Android.

1 - How we could switch env.rb from one platform to another in a practical way?

The features and step definitions will be mostly the same for both platforms but will eventually have differences, for example testing the back button behaviour in Android.

2 - Can we create some kind of PLATFORM global variable and create conditions, for example IF PLATFORM = ANDROID THEN ... in our step definitions and features?

Another approach would be to completely separate the source code for each platform, something like this:

E2E

----iOS

--------FEATURES

------------SUPPORT

----------------env.rb

----------------hooks.rb

------------STEP_DEFINITIONS

----------------home_steps.rb

------------Home.feature

----ANDROID

--------FEATURES

------------SUPPORT

----------------env.rb

----------------hooks.rb

------------STEP_DEFINITIONS

----------------home_steps.rb

------------Home.feature

This approach would have a much cleaner code without conditions for each platform but obviously the downside is that we would have to write all tests twice.

3 - Which approach do you think is better?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a question about Cucumber its much more about your application/organisation and how much stuff is specific to one particular platform. If you have lots of stuff that works differently on IOS vs Android and you develop them one platform at a time (e.g.have separate IOS/Android teams) then separate sets of features might be best.

If the vast majority of stuff is the same, then a single folder configurable to run on different platforms (perhaps using an environment variable to choose) would work. Or you could combine the two having `features ios-features android-features`.

Cucumber has a number of tools inside it which support working with different configurations inside a single folder. Remember env.rb is just a ruby file, so it can load environment variables and use those to change configurations. In addition you have tags and hooks, so you could have @ios-only scenarios for example, and you have profiles.

Comment: We will use the single folder approach using a paltform variable and use some logic to work with both. But we will probably have some specific tests as well so we will kind of combine both approaches as you said. In the end we decided to go with Python instead of Ruby but it won't change things too much I guess. Thanks for your insights!

Comment: @joseluisgonzalezclua, how did you run you your appium/cucumber test in app center. The test works fine on my local but not working in app center. It says test run: 0. It appears the test was not found. Does app center support cucumber at all?

Comment: In the end we decided to go with Appium/Python/Behave instad of Appium/Ruby/Cucumber. That blocked us from using App Center becase they do not support Appium/Python just Appium/Java. So we are evaluating BrowserStack and SauceLabs as a test cloud service and we will probably go with the former. As I didn't test App Center I don't know how to help you. I suggest you crate a new thread. Cheers.